# Auto Increment missing in my users table after importing on production. How should I modify it?

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, auto-increment

When I run this query :

```
ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=56;
```

It gives me error like :

> #1833 - Cannot change column 'id': used in a foreign key constraint
> 'designation_user_user_id_foreign' of table
> 'databasename.designation_user'

Comment: what type is users.id to start with?  are you trying to change the type or just set auto_increment?  it doesn't make much sense to have auto_increment on a foreign key constraint; presumably you should always be setting a value that is in the other table, or if not you shouldn't have the constraint

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here, what is the goal or outcome you’re wanting? Are you trying to fill a gap in the ID column left by deleting a record?

Comment: I suggest you back up production before you do anything. Also test your hypothesis by recovering to test environment.

Comment: *Is it safe ??* You have not provided enough info - you'd provide CREATE TABLE for both tables. Formally this is NOT safe. Safe method is: #1 - drop FK; #2 - modify column; #3 - recreate FK.

Comment: Is it safe? not sure. Make a backup. Side note: you should use migrations instead of importing directly in the database in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked!
I made `id` column in `users` table `unique` using more option in action column of `users` table and then executed below query :

```
ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```